# How to add a image to a Layout in Vaadin (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I would like to add an image to my web app, but I have some problems.

```java
private void newImage(){
    Image image = new Image("src/main/resources/images/sponsor.png");
    absoluteLayout.addComponent(image);
}
```

I did something like that and it doesn't work. I searched for something about `FileResource`, but I still don't know how to do this.

My image file is placed in the directory `src/main/resources/images`:

[image: sponsor.png inside the images directory]

I have also read the documentation site and it's still not working: https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-image.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots.

Comment: Ohh.. okay, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existence of an absolute layout component and a `Image` class with a constructor taking only one argument implies that you're using Vaadin 8 (or older) whereas the documentation you linked to is for Vaadin 10 and newer.

As can be seen from the screenshot, the constructor parameter that you're passing the image path to is named `caption`. This is thus a text that is shown next to the image rather than a reference to the image data itself.

You need to also assign a `Resource` to the image, either as a second constructor parameter or using the separate `setSource` method. With your file in `src/main/resources`, the easiest way is to use a `ClassResource` that loads the data from the classpath.

Taken together, a working example would thus be something like this:

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setSource(new ClassResource("/images/sponsor.png"));
```

Comment: ohh... I'm blind.. Thank You for help!